# Approximating derivatives using python

Tags: python, graph, numerical-methods, derivative

I have attempted to solve the following problem. I tried to solve it first with a set step size h using 0.1. However I need to change this in my code and use a for loop to loop through the values 0,1,..,20. I am a little confused how to do this problem but I was hoping to get some help with fixing the code I produced so far. Thanks!

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin

def derivative(func , x, h ):
    for h in range(20):
    return (func(x+h)-func(x))/h

def f(x):
    return sin(x)

print(derivative(f, pi/4))
```

Gives the output

```
0.6706029729039897
```

MY EDIT:

```
def derivative(func , x, h ):
    for h in range(20):
    return (func(x+h)-func(x))/h
```

Comment: Your example has syntax errors - please fix.

Comment: `hoping to get some help with fixing the code` - What is wrong? How is your code deficient? Where do you think the error is and why do you think that? You are importing numpy but not using it - is that just a distractor for us? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is asking you to compute the derivative using varying precision (represented using the variable `h`), and compare that to the exact/real derivative of the function.

Let `h` = 10 ^ -j, with j varying from 0 to 20. This means h will go (discretely) from 10⁻⁰ to 10⁻²⁰. You can use a `for`-loop and the `range(...)` function for that. Then pass that to the `derivative` function (to which you can a third parameter for the value of `h`)

```
def derivative(func, x, h):
    return (func(x + h) - func(x)) / h
```

Next, you need to compare that to the *exact* derivative. The function `f(x) = sin(x)` has a known (exact) derivative which is `cos(x)`. In math notation, `d(sin x)/dx = cos x`. This means that for any `x`, `cos(x)` will give you the exact derivative of `sin` at that `x`.

So you need to compare the result of the `derivative(...)` function to the value of `cos(x)`. This will give you the difference. You can then use the basic Python function `abs(x)` to get the absolute value of that difference, which will give you the absolute difference, which is the desired result. Do that for each `j` from 0 to 20 and store the results somewhere, in an array or a dict.

```
from math import sin, cos, pi

x = pi / 4
diffs = {}

for j in range(21): # range is exclusive so range(21) will stop at 20
    h = 10 ** -j
    deriv = derivative(sin, x, h)
    exact = cos(x)
    diff = abs(deriv - exact)
    diffs[h] = diff
```

Then, you can use pyplot's `loglog` function to plot those results on a graph, passing as X the `range(...)` result and as Y the array containing the results.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ordered = sorted(diffs.items())
x, y = zip(*ordered)
plt.loglog(x, y)
```

Comment: not sure if I will be able to complete it but I will give it a shot!

Comment: should h be its own function?

Comment: h is a variable. you should add it as a parameter to the `derivative` function. the definition should look like `def derivative(func, x, h):` and you should remove the `h = 0.1` line. then, when calling `derivative` you specify what h should be

Comment: I have made an edit at the bottom of my original question. But isn't h=10^-j?

Comment: I am a little confused, could you make an edit in your post to show this code?

Comment: thanks for that edit, that much makes sense! But then how can I put that together in a full code to solve my problem? Do I need to add in parts from my code? if you could edit that into a full code I can accept your answer

Comment: if you put each part one after the other you should have a working code, the only bits that remain are the matplotlib setup code (so that you can export to a picture or open a window, etc). directly posting full code is not really the spirit of SO, because that's basically doing homework for free. this website is for helping people learn stuff

Comment: okay I will figure that part out, thanks for your help! I will try and learn what you have showed me today

Comment: I am getting an error with the line x, y = *zip(*ordered)

Comment: thanks for that edit! its a bit of a strange plot, why is the x and y axis labelled like that?

Comment: is the y axis the absolute error? and the x axis the according step size?

Comment: @user123 the y-axis is the absolute error, the x-axis is the step size. you may need to call `plt.autoscale()` to set the axes automatically.

Comment: when I did that nothing changed. I will try and label the axis now myself. When we calculate the absolute error and we calculating it and each step size from 0 to 20 at Xo and comparing it to cosXo

Comment: and how did you store each value at each different step size in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181004/discussion-between-zdimension-and-user123).